# Flutter app: simple way to remember a user to do something

Tags: flutter

I have a cool flutter app which is used to track staff attendance. A user can check-in and check out when they start/stop working and the app record that event, calculate the number of hours worked and send a weekly summary to the manager of the staff expected wages. The current problem is that some staff members forget to check out (everyone is ok with check-in) so we don’t have good numbers and we need to manually change the attendance. I would like to add something to remember them to check out, and I am looking for creative ideas to do so. My objective is to make something very affordable.

So far I thought about two options:

- to use geolocation and track when staff get in/out of a certain location and log it as check-in and check out
- to set a timer when they start the shift and send a local notification if after xx hours they have not done the checkout

Geolocation seems to be the best because I can even automate the checkin/check out and do it in the backend but it will consme lots of resources in the client because I would need to check their location every while even when their at at home or on holiday...

The timer has some limits and still, I would need to manage background tasks that are complex as well as imprecise checkout depengin on when the notification goes out.

Do you have any suggestions on anything simple to implement?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the second option.
A simple scheduler which would look for all the employees who are checked in for more than x number of hours and then throw a clickable notification to checkout. It would be an easy and clean solution. However, it has several limitations as an employee might leave early but checkout later.

In my opinion, Your most clean solution would be to have an RFID/NFC check which automatically registers as a user checks out from the building.

Another thing that can be done if your employees are working mostly on their computers. There can be a browser extension or a web app which will clock in the time they are working on their laptops. Once they close it they will be automatically checked out.

Comment: Thansk for the comments! I guess RFID is more expensive than geolocation, since I need hardware on site. The employees in this app works on the shopfloor, so no laptops. My objective is to make something very affordable. Geolocation seems to be the best because I can even automate the checkin/check out and do it in the backend but it will consme lots of resources in the client because I would need to check their location every while even when their at at home or on holiday...